# A closed, path connected subset: is it a curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ closed sets are precisely the zero sets for continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Which closed sets can not be curves? Of course closed subsets which contain a closed disc or rectangle are not curves.

I came to following question:

> Let $C$ be the collection of those points $(x,y)$ where $y=\pm 2^nx$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, along with $y$-axis. Can it be a curve?

I was thinking that the point $(0,0)$ will make some problem to declare it to be a curve, but I could not justify it precisely.

Comment: It is the zero set of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1$.

Comment: What definition of curve is being used?